# How I can display an HTML asset file within my Flutter app on Windows?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter application and need to display an HTML file (index.html) stored as an asset within my app. The assets folder also contains additional HTML files. The app is targeted for the Windows platform, and I want to navigate from index.html to other HTML files within the assets folder.

I am seeking guidance on how to achieve this.

webview_universal: ^0.0.5
webview_windows: ^0.3.0